# How to make the VS Code PowerShell integrated console commands code the same color as the color theme in VS Code

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to find if there is a way to make the PowerShell integrated console commands code the same color as the color theme in VS Code.

So far everything I've found has only been about the theme colors for code inside files but nothing about changing the integrated console code colors.  I'm not even sure if this is possible inside the integrated PowerShell console.

Comment: I have also tried in the Insider version without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have expected that you could change the colours using the [Set-PSReadLineOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption) command as you can in the terminal but whilst Get-ReadLineOption returns results Set-PsReadLineOption does not change the colours so I expect that it is not possible

Also you won't be able to match the formatting exactly anyway as the colours available in Set-PsReadlineOption and the options are not compatible